# How do entry elements render a default string but also return an object at the same time?

Tags: php

So this is more of a PHP question than a Craft question, but the only example I can offer is one I've seen in Craft.

`{{ craft.entries.id(4).one() }}`

Returns a simple string like: "About Page"

`{{ dump(craft.entries.id(4).one()) }}`

Returns the entire element object.

From a PHP perspective, how does this work? Or where can I find out more about this practice?

It's a tricky thing to look up online and tracing through Craft's codebase hasn't offered much insight for a novice like me.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `__toString()` magic method:

> The __toString() method allows a class to decide how it will react
> when it is treated like a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring